# Как добавить постоянный вектор скорости\изменить вектор гравитации для "персонажа" при прикосновении к поверхности?

Tags: c#, unity3d

не могу понять как добавить постоянный вектор скорости, персонаж должен как бы при магнититься к стене или к потолку, добавляю velocity для потолка, что бы при касании проверкой потолка была скорость вектора вверх, персонаж падает вниз, силу ставил больше чем гравитация, не помогает

```
    [SerializeField] private float m_MaxSpeed = 10f;                    //speed x axis
    [SerializeField] private float m_MaxSpeedup = 6f;
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                 
    [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_PotolokSpeed = .5f;  
    [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                 
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                 
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_whatiswall;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_whatispotolok;

    private Transform m_GroundCheck;    
    const float k_GroundedRadius = .4f; 
    const float k_wallradius = .6f;     
    private bool m_Grounded;            
    private bool m_walled;
    private bool m_potolok;

    private Vector2 _speed;
    //private bool m_potolok;
    private Transform m_PotolokCheck;   
    private Transform m_wallingcheck;   
    const float k_PotolokRadius = .4f; 
    private Animator m_Anim;          
    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    private bool m_FacingRight = true;  

    void Update()
    {
        if (m_Grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));   //jump on ground
        }
        if (m_walled && !m_Grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) // jump on wall 
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity =new Vector2(6f, 6f); 
        }

        if (m_potolok && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) // 
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f,3));


        }


    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up references.
        m_GroundCheck = transform.Find("GroundCheck");
        m_PotolokCheck = transform.Find("PotolokCheck");
        m_wallingcheck = transform.Find("WallingCheck");
        m_Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {




        {
            m_Grounded = false;
            Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
            for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                    m_Grounded = true;
            }
            m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", m_Grounded);

            //vertical animation
            m_Anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        }
        {
            m_walled = false;
            Collider2D[] colliders =
                Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_wallingcheck.position, k_wallradius, m_whatiswall);
            for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                    m_walled = true;


            }

            m_Anim.SetBool("Wall", m_walled);

        }
        { 
        m_potolok = false;
            Collider2D[] colliders =
                Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_PotolokCheck.position, k_PotolokRadius, m_whatispotolok);
            for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                    m_potolok = true;
            }
            m_Anim.SetBool("Potolok", m_potolok);
        }


    }


    public void Move(float move, bool potolok, bool jump, bool jumpAx)//
    {
        //
        if (!potolok && m_Anim.GetBool("Potolochnik"))
        {
            // анимация при остановке на потолке
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_PotolokCheck.position, k_PotolokRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
            {
                potolok = true;

            }
        }


        m_Anim.SetBool("Potolochnik", potolok);


        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {

            move = (potolok ? move * m_PotolokSpeed : move);

            m_Anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));


            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * m_MaxSpeed, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);


            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {

                Flip();
            }

            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {

                Flip();
            }
        }

        if (m_Grounded && jump && m_Anim.GetBool("Ground"))
        {

            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }

    }


    private void Flip()
    {

        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;


        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Подключись отладчиком и убедись, что твои условия выполняются (твой код изобилует магическими константами - ну что может пойти не так? ;)). Если всё хорошо, объект обновляется, силы применяются, то сократи свой пример до минимума. Просто объект, который тянется к объекту, без каких-либо проверок на тип и нажатие кнопок. Ну а дальше методом половинного деления выяви проблемный код. Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть что-то вроде...

```
private bool _wallIsTouched;

Function FixedUpdate()
{
    if(_wallIsTouched)
        rigidbody.AddForce(VectorToWall * Physics.gravity * rigidbody.mass) 
}
```

Этот код написан чуть ли не от понта) 
Но направление точно это.

- Нужно использовать фиксед апдейт что бы твое ускорение не скакало при торможении графики,
- нужно использовать массу rigidbody
- и уровень гравитации всей системы что бы физика не выглядела адекватно на полу странной на стенах/потолке

но довылизывать код нужно будет тебе самому т.к. мне влом